# Communication failure with the network path

Tags: c#, .net, winapi, networking, passwords

I'm making a program to connect to a folder through a generic username and password, and I used the following program as a base:

```
public class ConnectToSharedFolder: IDisposable  
{  
    readonly string _networkName;  
  
    public ConnectToSharedFolder(string networkName, NetworkCredential credentials)  
    {  
        _networkName = networkName;  
  
        var netResource = new NetResource  
        {  
            Scope = ResourceScope.GlobalNetwork,  
            ResourceType = ResourceType.Disk,  
            DisplayType = ResourceDisplaytype.Share,  
            RemoteName = networkName  
        };  
  
        var userName = string.IsNullOrEmpty(credentials.Domain)  
            ? credentials.UserName  
            : string.Format(@"{0}\{1}", credentials.Domain, credentials.UserName);  
  
        var result = WNetAddConnection2(  
            netResource,  
            credentials.Password,  
            userName,  
            0);  
  
        if (result != 0)  
        {  
            throw new Win32Exception(result, "Error connecting to remote share");  
        }  
    }  
  
    ~ConnectToSharedFolder()  
    {  
        Dispose(false);  
    }  
  
    public void Dispose()  
    {  
        Dispose(true);  
        GC.SuppressFinalize(this);  
    }  
  
    protected virtual void Dispose(bool disposing)  
    {  
        WNetCancelConnection2(_networkName, 0, true);  
    }  
  
    [DllImport("mpr.dll")]  
    private static extern int WNetAddConnection2(NetResource netResource,  
        string password, string username, int flags);  
  
    [DllImport("mpr.dll")]  
    private static extern int WNetCancelConnection2(string name, int flags,  
        bool force);  
  
    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]  
    public class NetResource  
    {  
        public ResourceScope Scope;  
        public ResourceType ResourceType;  
        public ResourceDisplaytype DisplayType;  
        public int Usage;  
        public string LocalName;  
        public string RemoteName;  
        public string Comment;  
        public string Provider;  
    }  
  
    public enum ResourceScope : int  
    {  
        Connected = 1,  
        GlobalNetwork,  
        Remembered,  
        Recent,  
        Context  
    };  
  
    public enum ResourceType : int  
    {  
        Any = 0,  
        Disk = 1,  
        Print = 2,  
        Reserved = 8,  
    }  
  
    public enum ResourceDisplaytype : int  
    {  
        Generic = 0x0,  
        Domain = 0x01,  
        Server = 0x02,  
        Share = 0x03,  
        File = 0x04,  
        Group = 0x05,  
        Network = 0x06,  
        Root = 0x07,  
        Shareadmin = 0x08,  
        Directory = 0x09,  
        Tree = 0x0a,  
        Ndscontainer = 0x0b  
    }  
}
```

And it was working correctly, but during this week the program stopped working and reported the following error:

```
if (result != 0) 
 
        {  
            throw new Win32Exception(result, "Error connecting to remote share");  
        }
```

And I verified that the generic user still has access to the folder, and I don't know how to solve this problem, could anyone help me?

As I am using this program as a class, here is how I am calling the function:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string networkPath,username,password;
            networkPath = @"\networkPath";
            username = "usarname";
            password = "password";
            NetworkCredential credentials = new NetworkCredential(username,password);
            using (new ConnectToSharedFolder(networkPath, credentials))
            {
                // I do the rest of the logic here
            }
        }
```

Comment: So what's result value? Also, just `throw new Win32Exception(result)` - don't mask original error text.

Comment: So I didn't check the result, and I'll only be able to check the result on Monday, because it's a problem with my work, but in the case you say to hide the throw new Win32Exception(result)?? @Simon Mourier

Comment: No I didn't say that.

Comment: The function is obsolete.  You need to use "2A" (or 2W, 3A, 3W).  See : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winnetwk/nf-winnetwk-wnetaddconnection2a.  Probably something recently changed to inhibit the older method.

Comment: Got it, I'll check on monday, thanks for the help @jdweng

Comment: Looks like your code will only work with 16-bit versions of Windows.  What are your project settings?  Code may work if you use x86 option.

Comment: So about the bit configuration of the project, I can only find out and answer you on monday because it was on the work computer, but I'll look at these two tips you gave me, thank you very much. @jdweng

Comment: You should also specify the charset on both `DllImport` and the `StructLayout` attributes

Comment: Guys, the program started working again, but another person on my team is trying to access the folder with the same generic user to perform another application, but it's giving error 1219 in her program, is it possible to force a disconnection at the end of this program?

Comment: According to the Doc:[System Error Codes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/debug/system-error-codes--1000-1299-?redirectedfrom=MSDN)
ERROR_SESSION_CREDENTIAL_CONFLICT
1219 （0x4C3）
Multiple connections to a server or shared resource by the same user, using more than one user name, are not allowed. Disconnect all previous connections to the server or shared resource and try again.

Comment: Yes, but in the case of the program that I put above, is it possible to modify it to force the user to disconnect, after carrying out the application?